# div with 'display:table-row' blown by content IE 11 (overflow-y)

Tags: html, css, overflow

Currently I'm struggling with solving a CSS-Layout problem.
I've got a div that is positioned absolute on the page and in which there should be variable sized divs and one div that goes to the bottom of the page.

My idea was to solve this via display:table, display:table-row, as you can see in this fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6sg2Lx6b/6/

In Chrome, Safari everything works as it should, but guess what... in IE11 ( Virtual Machine) it does not work at all. If the content inside the table-row at the bottom of the page reaches a certain height, the whole body seems to grow with the contents.

I tried almost everything, but still could not find a working solution. ( I thought IE11 might have gotten better over the last years...)

Comment: Well, those `display:table...` properties are meant to emulate actual tables. So the first thing to do is see what happens if you put elements with `display:table-cell` inside the table rows instead of plain text nodes. Also, `color-green` is a horrible class name.

Comment: I will try that out, but I think I've already tried it... Haha, yeah I'd never choose that class name for the actual project, that was just for fiddle.